# Terminology / notation for the set of variables associated with a distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, notation

Suppose I have a conditional (or any) distribution as so:

$$
p(A \mid B,C,D)
$$
and in the text, I want to refer to the variables $\{A,B,C,D\}$ associated with that density (or mass). Is there a formal name or notation for this set? What is the formal way of referring to it? Is there a commonly used symbol?

It is not the support of the distribution as far as I understand the definition of support, so what would it be called?

Thanks

Comment: Almost always things go in the opposite direction.  You don't start with a distribution and then come up with a random variable $(A,B,C,D)$ following that distribution: that variable is not determined by the distribution.  Instead, you begin with the (possibly multivariate) random variable and it "follows" or "is governed by" a (joint) distribution, which *is* determined by the random variable.  You can name things anything you like, but conventions lean towards capital letters late in the alphabet -- $X,Y,Z,U,V,W$ -- for random variables and versions of $F$ or $D$ for distributions.

Comment: Quite but I am wondering if the collective set of random variables that follow $p()$ has a specific name. That they are random variables and that they follow the distribution is fine, but the associated terminology of those (collective) random variables is the question.

Comment: When one begins by specifying the random variables, it would seem there is no terminological issue at all: they have already been named.

Comment: They have not been named, not the collection of them. The symbolic form used is fine; I am again looking for the collective name of the random variables that follow some given distribution, be it joint or conditional, doesn't matter. If there is no such term, that's fine, but if there is then I am wondering if there is something more specific than 'random variables that follow a given distribution'.

Comment: I don't follow, because in your question they are explicitly named $(A,B,C,D).$

Comment: I see, okay to put it into example terms: $S = \{A,B,C,D\}$ - what is $S$ called if anything at all? Is there even a name for that set?

Comment: It's called a multivariate random variable or a vector-valued random variable.

Comment: $A$ could also be a multivariate random variable. Again I am looking for the name of the set of variables (multivariate or not) associated with a given distribution.

Comment: That's immaterial: you are only discussing your notation for a random variable; namely, what which you wish to use to designate which sets of components.  Your language still suggests (misleadingly IMHO) that a distribution determines a random variable.  That is not the case.

Comment: It is not immaterial. You are misunderstanding the question, repeated four times now. The focus of this question is not which variables follow what distribution or the dynamics therein simply if there exists semantics for that collection of variables. That is all. Yes, they are random variables, of course they are; it is a stochastic distribution. Yes, they follow a distribution. All I want to know is if there exists vocabulary to refer to the 'letters inside the density' - I do not know how much clearer I can be at this point. That _set_ is not a multivariate random variable. It is a set.

Comment: I'm afraid we disagree about the mathematical terminology.  If you consider that $(A,B,C,D)$ has a joint distribution, then it perforce *must* be a multivariate random variable.  And if, after all this back and forth, I continue to misunderstand your question, please contemplate the possibility that others will misunderstand it too and see whether you can edit your post to help them appreciate what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Hopefully, our discussion will elucidate the question being asked. If not I will have to edit it.